# Replace source of featured image with thumbnail source?

Tags: jquery

I have 1 main image and several thumbnail images. When you click the thumbnail image I want the main image to update with the thumbnails image source.

So far I figured out how to change the main image source file if you click a thumbnail and I also figured out how to get "this thumbnails source" so its dynamic but I'm not sure how to put them together?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent-thumb img.thumb').click(function () {
      alert($(this).attr('src'));
      $('#picture').attr('src', 'images/short.png');
    });
 });
```

So basically the "Alert value" would replace "images/short.png"

Thanks for any help

Comment: `$('#picture').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));`?

Comment: In programming, if you've got something that gets you what you want, put it in a variable. Then, use that variable where you want that thing to go. Or, just put what you want directly where you want it to go, as suggested by @j08691.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('#picture').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
```

`.attr( attributeName )` gets the value of the attribute for the set of matched elements.
`.attr( attributeName, value )` set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: I am trying this do u see anything wrong with it?

    (function($){

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ba-list-gallery img').click(function () {
      $('.featured-ba img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
 });
    })(jQuery);